# Error - The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure as following:

```
as  
  if(@ItemRefID = 47011 and @Operation = 16)
  begin 
     declare @TotalSP int 
     declare @TotalSPMastery int 
     
     SELECT 
         @TotalSP = SUM(_RefSkill.ReqLearn_SP) 
     FROM 
         SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._RefSkill, SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._CharSkill 
     WHERE 
         _RefSkill.ID = _CharSkill.SkillID 
         AND _CharSkill.CharID = @CharID 
         AND _RefSkill.ReqCommon_MasteryLevel1 <= '110' 

     SELECT 
         @TotalSPMastery = SUM(_RefLevel.Exp_M) 
     FROM 
         SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._CharSkillMastery, SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._RefLevel 
     WHERE 
         _RefLevel.Lvl = _CharSkillMastery.Level 
         AND _CharSkillMastery.CharID = @CharID 
         AND _CharSkillMastery.Level <= '110' 
         
     UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Char 
     SET RemainSkillPoint = RemainSkillPoint + @TotalSP + @TotalSPMastery + 200000 
     WHERE CharID = @CharID 

     DELETE _CharSkill 
     FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._RefSkill, SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._CharSkill 
     WHERE _RefSkill.ID = _CharSkill.SkillID 
      AND _CharSkill.CharID = @CharID 
      AND _RefSkill.ReqCommon_MasteryLevel1 <= '110' 
      AND _RefSkill.ID NOT IN (1, 70, 40, 2, 8421, 9354, 9355, 11162, 9944, 8419, 8420, 11526, 10625) 

    UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._CharSkillMastery 
    SET Level = '0' 
    WHERE CharID = @CharID AND Level <= '110'
```

But I get these error messages:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure _AddLogItem, Line 23
> The multi-part identifier "_RefSkill.ID" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure _AddLogItem, Line 23
> The multi-part identifier "_CharSkill.SkillID" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure _AddLogItem, Line 23
> The multi-part identifier "_CharSkill.CharID" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure _AddLogItem, Line 23
> The multi-part identifier "_RefSkill.ReqCommon_MasteryLevel1" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure _AddLogItem, Line 23
> The multi-part identifier "_RefSkill.ReqLearn_SP" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure _AddLogItem, Line 24
> The multi-part identifier "_RefLevel.Lvl" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure _AddLogItem, Line 24
> The multi-part identifier "_CharSkillMastery.Level" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure _AddLogItem, Line 24
> The multi-part identifier "_CharSkillMastery.CharID" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure _AddLogItem, Line 24
> The multi-part identifier "_CharSkillMastery.Level" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure _AddLogItem, Line 24
> The multi-part identifier "_RefLevel.Exp_M" could not be bound.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Well for one thing: you **cannot** delete from two tables at once:

```
DELETE _CharSkill 
FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._RefSkill, SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._CharSkill
```

This is invalid T-SQL syntax - you'll have to delete from each table separately.

And also, you're still using the old SQL-89 "join" syntax:

```
SELECT 
     @TotalSP = SUM(_RefSkill.ReqLearn_SP) 
FROM 
     SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._RefSkill, SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._CharSkill 
WHERE 
     _RefSkill.ID = _CharSkill.SkillID
```

which has been replaced with the SQL-92 standard (**more than 20 years ago!**) by the proper ANSI JOIN syntax - this is the **preferred** way of joining - you should get in the habit of using this "new" syntax!

```
SELECT 
     @TotalSP = SUM(_RefSkill.ReqLearn_SP) 
FROM 
     SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._RefSkill
INNER JOIN  
     SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._CharSkill ON _RefSkill.ID = _CharSkill.SkillID
```

This makes it much clearer *what* you're joining, and *what* the JOIN condition is (it's not hidden away amongst all the other `WHERE` conditions somewhere - it's clear and obvious)

Comment: +1 for citing the standard as to why `INNER JOIN` is preferred over implicit joining.  I see implicit joins often lambasted but not _why_.